# .StartsWith and .Contains are returning null when comparing dates

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my application, I was trying to pull out the sum of values in a specific column for a specific period of time. For example if I want it to pull the sum for every month I did something like this

```
var thisDate = DateTime.Now;
var currentDay = thisDate.Day;
var thisMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
var thisYear = thisDate.Year.ToString();
var thisYearthisMonth = string.Format("{0}-{1}", thisYear, thisMonth);
var SpecifiedTotal = (from t in db.Transaction
                      where t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId
                      && t.Status.Status == "Approved"
                      && t.DateApproved.ToString().StartsWith(thisYearthisMonth)
                      select (decimal?)t.AmountApproved).Sum() ?? 0;
```

Setting a breakpoint showed me that SpecifiedTotal was evaluating to zero. I tried to find out why by removing the line `&& t.DateApproved.ToString().Contains(thisYearthisMonth)` and it evaluated to the right value. In essence i tried to pull out the sum of the values in a column for the period of March i.e 2015-03 so i thought comparing the stored date with that by finding any date that starts with 2015-03 would make sense. What could i have done wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Without trying to work out exactly this fails, I would *strongly* recommend not using string representations for this sort of thing anyway. Just use `DateTime` comparisons instead - assuming that `DateApproved` is a `DateTime` column, of course. (If it's not, make it so!)

```
var thisDate = DateTime.Now;
var start = new DateTime(thisDate.Year, thisDate.Month, 1);
var end = start.AddMonths(1);
var specifiedTotal = (from t in db.Transaction
                      where t.AgentId == CurrentUser.SalesAgent.AgentId
                      && t.Status.Status == "Approved"
                      && t.DateApproved >= start && t.DateApproved < end
                      select (decimal?)t.AmountApproved).Sum() ?? 0;
```

In general, you should avoid using string operations unless you're *actually* interested in text. In this case, you're not - you're trying to perform a range comparison on dates. That has nothing to do with textual representations of them.

Comment: @jtimperley If a provider like EF or Ling-To-SQL cannot translate the LINQ to SQL then it will not compile.  It only pulls the records into memory if you materialize the Linq query.

Comment: @juharr: No, it will often *compile*, but fail to execute. For example, try using a call to `GetHashCode()` in a query... no compile-time error, but it'll fail at execution time. But I agree that it won't silently pull everything in and filter at the client instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are of course correct.  I think my brain has already checked out for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Because StartsWith is a stricter match than Contains? Have you tried checking to see what format your DateApproved is in?

Comment: @JonSkeet does your code take into consideration 30 days in some month and 31 days in some months?